# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name. Couldn't get my springboot application running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am new to Microservices and started building one with a simple Get and Post implementations. I am getting an error about bean creation and unsatisfied Dependency Exception. Please find my code attached.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

**DbServiceApplication.java(under package com.example.dbservice)**

```
package com.example.dbservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.dbservice.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DbServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DbServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**QuotesRepository.java (under package com.example.dbservice.repository)**

```
package com.example.dbservice.repository;

import com.example.dbservice.model.Quote;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface QuotesRepositpory extends JpaRepository<Quote, Integer> {
    List<Quote> findByUserName(String username);
}
```

**DbServiceResource (under repository com.example.dbservice.resource)**

```
package com.example.dbservice.resource;


import com.example.dbservice.model.Quote;
import com.example.dbservice.model.Quotes;
import com.example.dbservice.repository.QuotesRepositpory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/db")
public class DbServiceResource {

    private QuotesRepositpory quotesRepository;

    public DbServiceResource(QuotesRepositpory quotesRepository) {
        this.quotesRepository = quotesRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public List<String> getQuotes(@PathVariable("username")
                                  final String username){

        return quotesRepository.findByUserName(username)
                .stream()
                .map(Quote::getQuote)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }


    @PostMapping("/add")
    public List<String> add(@RequestBody final Quotes quotes){
        return null;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Error Stack trace**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-08-03 12:02:21.462  INFO 10968 --- [           main] c.t.s.dbservice.DbServiceApplication     : Starting DbServiceApplication on JAGWANIA01 with PID 10968 (C:\Users\jagwania\Desktop\db-service\target\classes started by jagwania in C:\Users\jagwania\Desktop\db-service)
2018-08-03 12:02:21.469  INFO 10968 --- [           main] c.t.s.dbservice.DbServiceApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-03 12:02:21.675  INFO 10968 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@5c86a017: startup date [Fri Aug 03 12:02:21 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/jagwania/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-08-03 12:02:24.991  INFO 10968 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cc6bebb7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-08-03 12:02:25.877  INFO 10968 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8300 (http)
2018-08-03 12:02:25.936  INFO 10968 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-03 12:02:25.936  INFO 10968 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-08-03 12:02:25.960  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Geth;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.4-bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin;C:\Users\jagwania\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.255  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-03 12:02:26.255  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4587 ms
2018-08-03 12:02:26.433  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.441  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.441  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.441  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.441  INFO 10968 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-03 12:02:26.802  INFO 10968 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-08-03 12:02:27.352  INFO 10968 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-08-03 12:02:27.448  INFO 10968 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-08-03 12:02:27.487  INFO 10968 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Aug 03 12:02:27 CDT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2018-08-03 12:02:27.894  INFO 10968 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.17.Final}
2018-08-03 12:02:27.898  INFO 10968 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-08-03 12:02:27.928  WARN 10968 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2018-08-03 12:02:27.928  INFO 10968 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-08-03 12:02:27.964  INFO 10968 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-08-03 12:02:27.969  INFO 10968 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-03 12:02:27.993  INFO 10968 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-03 12:02:28.005 ERROR 10968 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.example.dbservice.DbServiceApplication.main(DbServiceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: there is not `com.techprimers.stock.dbservice.repository` package in your project. Or at least the beans you are trying to use are not part of it.

Answer (score 1):

In spring configuration, you have declared the base package of your jpa repositories in "com.techprimers.stock.dbservice.repository"
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.techprimers.stock.dbservice.repository")`

But from the repository code, actually it is inside package "com.example.dbservice.repository"

So change the base package in configuration like:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.dbservice.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DbServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DbServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Update:
Now the error is for jaxb components missing, java.xml.bind was part of java till jdk 8 and is deprecated from 9. Add following in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You also missed to add `@Autowired` in your controller constructor.

Comment: The version in the dependency still causes a problem
It throws an error as
Dependency 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11' not found less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Inspects a Maven model for resolution problems

Comment: I'm not sure from where you are getting 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11'. I've asked to add version 2.30

Comment: Sorry it was a type. I did 2.3.0 but the main error is the same.
Or do we need to find PersistenceContext dependency coming from different JARs and need to remove the extra dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I did check your project as far as I could, and I found some problems related to your code which might help you to reduce the problem.

1. Remove the hibernate core dependency as it is not necessary since you added JPA dependency and it already contains the hibernate-core dependency.
2. Which java version you are using? some part of hibernate components are not compatible with java 8/11 .
3. Use @EntityScan, so entities could be easily find in the correct directory.